# Putting a superscript in a label in xcode8

Tags: swift, xcode8

I am creating a math app and would like to have a superscript 2. I have been unable to find a solution for xcode 8 that isn't a base line off set

```
finalFunc.text = "Converted: \(printA)(x+\(printB))^2+\(printC)"
```

Comment: Have you checked the answer?

Comment: i have tried it and i get 2 errors. it says expected deceleration attString and that font cant be used within initializer :( any thoughts? and thanks for the help!

Comment: Can u show your tried code where you get errors?

Comment: I get the errors on line 3 and 4 of ur answer?

Comment: What's the error?

Answer (score 2):

**Updated for `Swift4`**

```
let font:UIFont? = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size:20)
let fontSuper:UIFont? = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size:10)
let attString:NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "xcode8", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font:font!])
attString.setAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.font:fontSuper!,NSAttributedString.Key.baselineOffset:10], range: NSRange(location:5,length:1))

labelname.attributedText = attString
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code -

```
let font:UIFont? = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size:20)
let fontSuper:UIFont? = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size:10)
let attString:NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "xcode8", attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:font!])
attString.setAttributes([NSFontAttributeName:fontSuper!,NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName:10], range: NSRange(location:5,length:1))
label1.attributedText = attString;
```

Output -

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For a **simple to use Swift solution**, you might want to checkout **[HandyUIKit](https://github.com/Flinesoft/HandyUIKit)**. After importing it into your project (e.g. via Carthage – see instructions in README) you can do something like this:

```
import HandyUIKit

let someFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20, weight: .medium)
"Converted: \(printA)(x+\(printB))^{2}+\(printC)".superscripted(font: someFont)
```

The last line will return an `NSAttributedString` which will look exactly like **what you're looking for**. Just **assign it** to a `UILabel`s **`attributedText`** property and **that's it!**

---

If you're looking for **subscripting** a text, simply use `subscripted(font:)` instead. It will recognize structures like `CO_{2}`. There's also `superAndSubscripted(font:)` if you want to combine **both**.

See the [docs](https://github.com/Flinesoft/HandyUIKit#superscriptedfont--subscriptedfont--superandsubscriptedfont) for more information and additional examples.